# Using Horizon with Sitecore JSS site

Tags: horizon, jss

I have a website developed in Blazor server app based on Sitecore JSS layout ... the json of each page is pulled using /sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=xxx and Sitecore really does not know any UI layout about this site so our content authors lost the native experience editing capability, now my boss want me to find a way to allow content authors to edit the content using Horizon and she insisted it is possible. I have googled and I could not find any hints or blogs on that, can someone tell me how it can be done if Sitecore does not have all the UI layouts structure, css, js ... can render the content as it looks in the blazor website and be able to edit it? via Horizon extension?

Comment: Sounds like you're consuming from Sitecore directly as a Headless CMS, instead of using the framework. It's possible to support EE in Blazor, but it's not officialy by Sitecore. These might help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8whszfkSqrg
https://github.com/jss-blazor/jss-blazor

Comment: the link is using webassembly blazor - mine is using blazor server app

Comment: Hi @John and welcome to Sitecore Community. Check this repo https://github.com/GoranHalvarsson/SitecoreBlazor

Comment: Thanks @PeterProcházka that link is our project is based - now we need to understand how Horizon can edit the JSS site.

Comment: Hey @John, thank you for using my repo :-)
I'm really glad that you guys are using it. Blazor rocks